# Enable photos update in OneDrive for iPhone SE 2020

Tags: iphone, photos, photo-stream, onedrive

**tl;dr** *Even though Camera Upload is enabled in OneDrive app in my iPhone SE 2020, it seems to be not working at all. Neither new nor existing photos are never uploaded to OneDrive. I also cannot find any way to select a destination folder to which photos will be uploaded.*

---

#### The Problem

On my iPhone SE 2020 in *OneDrive* app I cannot:

- Enable *Camera Upload* functionality (actually: I can enable it, but it isn't working)
- Select a destination folder in OneDrive, to which photos will be uploaded

#### Configuration

I went to *OneDrive* → *[user photo]* → *Settings* → *Camera Uploaded* and set:

- *[my private account]*: **on**
- *Upload Using Mobile Data*: **on**
- *Include Videos*: **on**
- *Organise new uploads*: **Months**
- *Reupload From Original Formats* → *Reupload Still Photos as Live Photos*: **off**

No more options found in this section of *Settings* in *OneDrive* app. No way to tell *OneDrive*, which folder I want it to upload my photos to.

#### Results

- Neither newly captured nor existing photos are ever uploaded.
- Phone has an uninterrupted access to the Internet using two various sources (home Wi-Fi and mobile GPRS data).
- Any other Internet-depended application is accessing the web in the same time without any problems.

#### Hardware Gear

- Model: **iPhone SE**
- System: **iOS 16.3.1**

The functionality **is not working**.

What am I missing? What else must I check or try?

**EDIT**: *The described functionality doesn't work in OneDrive app running on Apple products only (if that matters). It works without any problems in OneDrive app running on a variety of Android-powered devices.*

Comment: If you open the OneDrive app, does it start to upload photos?

Comment: @Allan No, it does not. Your comment however enlighten me into correct direction. Turned out that my OneDrive was somewhat "stuck". Logging-off from the account and login back resolved the issue and photos started to be uploaded.

Comment: I am unsure what to do in this case? Could this solution be worth to someone else (and I should answer my own question) or is it "Too narrow. Works fine here" (and I should rather delete the question)?

Comment: Post this as an answer.  If you experienced the issue, there’s a good chance someone else will.  When you write it, but sure to ping me again in comments so I can up vote.

Comment: @Allan Pinging you, as requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that the solution was to simply log-off from the account in OneDrive and login again.

It seems that the described problem was caused by the fact that OneDrive for Mac has become some kind of "blocked" or something like that. It was working normally except for the above mentioned photo upload. After re-login functionality started to work normally.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!